# Complexity of std::inplace_merge

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, space-complexity

So I have two sorted vectors and I wanted to merge them into a single sorted vector without using an additional vector.

Since there's this condition I can't use **std::merge**, so I tried [std::inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge).

I have this function which takes both vectors and two numbers **m** and **n** which are the number of elements in each vector. Here's how I solved this problem:

```
void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) 
    {
         auto it = std::remove_if(std::execution::par, nums1.begin() + m, nums1.end(), 
             [](const int val)
             {
                 return val == 0;
             }
         );
         nums1.erase(it, nums1.end());

        nums1.insert(nums1.end(), nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
        std::inplace_merge(std::execution::par, nums1.begin(), nums1.begin() + nums1.size() - nums2.size(), nums1.end());
    }
```

#### Example case

```
vec 1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
m = 3
vec2 = [2,5,6]
n = 3
```

Expected Output: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

#### My attempt at finding space and time complexity

this is all working fine, now what I want is to find out the time and space complexity.
I came up with the following:

The space complexity would be the size of the total vector right? In this case I believe it's **O(m + n)**

As for the time complexity, std::remove_if would take at most **m** , so will **std::vector::erase** and std::vector::insert would take **n** (the number of elements in the second vector) and finally **std::inplace_merge** would take O(n log n).

So in the end we have **O(n log n + 2m + n)**, am I correct ?

Comment: Any attempt to read the [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge)?

Comment: Why not just benchmark it and find out? Work up through various values of N from 10^0 through 10^M.

Comment: @tadman benchmarking is never a bad idea, but it can't tell you the *guaranteed* complexity.

Comment: @MarkRansom It certainly won't but it's better than guessing, and often the documentation discusses the theoretical performance on idealized hardware that doesn't exist, so real-world testing is imperative if it is performance critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculations are mostly correct, but:

1. You're mixing your parameters; the `n` you use changes meaning between number of elements in one vector and number of elements in the combined vector.
2. Traditionally, big-O notation ignores constant factors, and any terms that are dwarfed by a higher big-O expression. So `2m` is the same thing as `m`, and if `n` is a superset of `m`, then `n log n` means you ignore the `2m` term entirely.
3. Similarly, you combine terms that are effectively the same thing (so having `m` for `nums1` and `n` for `nums2` is pretty meaningless; the `n log n` work is on the *combined* size; you'd usually ignore the distinction between the two inputs).
4. Your space complexity (if you're not dropping constant factors) is arguably `O(m + 2n)`, since you're not consuming the elements from the second vector, you're copying them (so you end up with one copy of each element in `nums1`, and two of each element in `nums2`). But of course, per #2/#3, that's more detail than you'd use for big-O notation.

So in big-O terms, you'd express the time complexity as simply `O(n log n)` (`n` being the combined size of both inputs), and the space complexity as `O(n)` (it needs up to `2n` space, if `nums1` is empty and `nums2` contains all the data, but constant factors don't matter to big-O). As the input sizes grow, those are the dominating terms, everything else becomes irrelevant from a theoretical perspective (even if those practical concerns might actually matter in real life).

Note that, in practice, [`std::inplace_merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) will attempt to allocate temporary space if possible, and if it succeeds, the time complexity (in terms of number of comparisons needed) drops to `O(n)`, so the real world space used may be higher than you expect, while the time may grow more slowly than expected.

Comment: Thank you, I probably shoud've mentioned the constraint n >= m

Comment: @IRP_HANDLER: That doesn't change anything, insofar as `m` (length of `nums1`) is defined in terms of `n` (length of `nums2`), so you can treat it as bounded by their combined length, since the key operation, the `inplace_merge`, is bounded by their combined length anyway. You could also use the length of `nums2` as the bounding limit anyway with equivalent effect, since `m` can't grow faster than it anyway.